# What would be the time complexity of merging k sorted linked lists by using the concept of merging 2 sorted lists?

Tags: data-structures, linked-list, time-complexity

I want to know the true time complexity of `merging k sorted lists` if I use the algorithm of merging 2 sorted linked lists.

I have seen somewhere that time complexity would be  O(nk) and somewhere as O(nk^2).
(k is the number of sorted lists and n is the number of elements in a list).
So I am confused with the time complexity of this problem.

Please tell me the true time complexity of this problem.

Comment: It should be `O(N*K)` (where N*K = total elements in all lists) and using `heap O(N * logK)`.

Comment: https://youtu.be/wugaUVZ8PVw?t=147

please have a watch to this video...
from 2:29 to 9:00

(in this case, the time complexity is O(nk^2)).

Comment: *"I have seen somewhere that time complexity would be O(nk) and somewhere as O(nk^2)"*: Could you please add the sources for both claims *inside* the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to know the true time complexity of merging  sorted lists if I use the algorithm of merging 2 sorted linked lists.

There are several algorithms to choose from.

We define  as the (maximum) number of values in one sorted list, so that the total number of values is bounded by . A clear definition of  is important, as some will define it as the *total* number of values in all lists together -- which obviously leads to different formulas. I will define that total number of values as . So =

### Naive Algorithm

This algorithm merges the first two lists, then merges the result with the third list, then the result with the fourth list, ...etc.

This algorithm will need to perform −1 merges, and each merge will concern  more items than the previous one. The first merge involves two lists of  elements, so it is O(2)

We thus have the following relation :

(2) = O(2)
        () = (−1) + O()

And so:

() = O(∑<sub><sub>=2..</sub></sub>) = O(²) = O()

The last step uses the formula for [triangular numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1_%2B_2_%2B_3_%2B_4_%2B_%E2%8B%AF)

### Divide and Conquer Algorithm

A (binary) divide-and-conquer algorithm defines the base case for when you only have 2 lists, and merges them with the known algorithm. In all other cases it merges the two lists that come out of recursion. This really is the principle that [merge sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort) uses.

Now the recurrence relation is as follows:

(2) = O(2)
        () = 2(/2) + O()

If we expand this relation once, we get:

() = 2(2(/4) + O(/2)) + O() = 4(/4) + O() + O()

If you expand it again:

() = 8T(/8) + O(3)

After log<sub><sub>2</sub></sub> − 1 expansions:

() = (/2)(2) + O(log)

Substituting (2), we get:

() = O() + O(log) = O(log) = O(log)

### Heap-based Algorithm

When you create a binary min-heap, where each entry is a linked list, keyed by the value of its first node, then you can repeatedly pull the list from heap that has the smallest element, extract that element from that list, and insert that list again in the heap, where it will find its place based on its new key (since it has now one node less). If a list becomes empty, it is no longer inserted into the heap.

Building the heap costs O(). One heap extraction and insertion costs O(log). There are  extractions to do, so the complexity is O() + O(log) = O(log) = O(log)

Comment: https://youtu.be/kpCesr9VXDA?t=141

please have a watch to this video (from 2:20 to 4:05) he is claiming that time complexity would be O(nk) for the naive algorithm.

I think he(the person who is telling O(nk)) is wrong.

Comment: @AbhishekJaiswal, in that video defines  as the *total* number of values, so it is also correct.